# How to show that the normal subgroups in tower subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

We say a tower $G=G_0\supseteq G_1 \supseteq G_2\dots \supseteq G_m$ is abelian if it is normal (i.e., each $G_{i+1}$ is normal in $G_i$) and if each factor group $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is abelian.

I am working on the following exercise.

Let $G$ be a solvable group. (That means group $G$ has an abelian tower, whose last element is the trivial subsgroup.) Show that there exists an abelian tower $G=G_0\supseteq G_1 \supseteq G_2\dots \supseteq G_m=\{e\}$ so that each $G_i$ is normal subgroup of $G$?

---

I just try to verify the definition of  normal subgroup. For every $g\in G$, I try to show that
$$
gG_{i}g^{-1}=G_i
$$

Since each $G_{i}$ is normal subgroup in $G_{i-1}$, then for every $g_{i-1}\in G_{i-1}$, we have
$$
g_{i-1}G_{i}g_{i-1}^{-1}=G_{i}
$$

Then repeat this one we get for $g_{i-2}\in G_{i-2}$, $$g_{i-2}G_{i-1}g_{i-1}^{-1}=G_{i-1}$$.

I am stuck here. But I did not use the condition 'each factor group $G_i\setminus G_{i+1}$ is abelian'...

---

I also find this note:https://users.math.msu.edu/users/ruiterj2/Math/Documents/Fall%202016/Algebra/Theorems.pdf
In page 9,

> Theorem 1.81 Every $p$-group is solvable.

> Theorem 1.82 Let $G$ be a non-trivial $p$-group. Then there exists a sequence of subgroups
> $$G=G_0\supseteq G_1 \supseteq G_2\dots \supseteq G_m=\{e\}$$
> such that  $G_i$ is normal in $G$ and $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is cyclic of order $p$.

Comment: You are missing a `)` in your first sentence. Probably after "$G_i$".

Comment: `G_{i}\setminus G_{i+1}`, as the command suggests, means the elements that are in $G_i$ but not in $G_{i+1}$. The quotient is $G_i/G_{i+1}$, with just a `/`.

Comment: How about my proof?

Comment: Your calculations don't make sense to me. "Since $G_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{i-1}$, then for every $g_i\in G_i$ we have $g_iG_{i-1}g_i^{-1} = G_{i-1}$." That isn't normality: you are conjugating the *overgroup* by an element of the *subgroup*. **Of course** you get the overgroup. So what?

Comment: Note that you are trying to prove that $G_i$ is normal in $G$. But you final equation does not even feature $G_i$ at all. How could this be a proof that $G_i$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: Yes. I am wrong. I am stuck here. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: @LukasHeger What? But this an exercise in the textbook. Are you sure this one is impossible?

Comment: @LukasHeger I checked the definition of supersolable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group. But in this question, we just need to prove $H_i$ is normal in G but we do not need each  quotient group $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is cyclic. It seems different?

Comment: @LukasHeger I also find two theorems and I added in my question. It seems that for $p$-group, we can find this one?

Comment: @Hermi you're right, sorry for the confusion

Comment: The standard proof is to use the derived series of the group as the abelian tower in which all subgroups in the tower are normal in $G$,

Comment: It is true that every solvable group has *an* abelian series in which every term is normal in the whole group. However, it is **false** that in every abelian series of a solvable group all groups must be normal in the whole group, and *that* seems to be what you are attempting to rove. You won't be able to, because it isn't true.

Comment: By the way: I can't parse your subject line. Maybe you can correct it, so future users can understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to prove that if $G$ is solvable, then in *any* abelian tower all subgroups that appear in the tower are normal in the whole group. That is not true. What is true is that if $G$ is solvable, then *there exists* an abelian tower for $G$ in which all subgroups in the tower are normal in $G$.

For a counterexample to the statement you seem to be trying to prove, start with the Klein $4$-group, $C_2\times C_2$, written as $\{1, x, y, xy\}$ (that is, $x\leftrightarrow (g,e)$, $y\leftrightarrow(e,g)$, and $xy\leftrightarrow (g,g)$, where $C_2$ is generated by $g$); let $G=(C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_3$, with $C_3$ generated by an element $z$ and $z$ acting on $C_2\times C_2$ by sending $x\mapsto xy\mapsto y\mapsto x$.

Then $G$ has an abelian series given by
$$\{1\} \subseteq \{1,x\}\subseteq \{1,x,y,xy\}\subseteq G.$$
If we let $G_0=G$, $G_1=\{1.x,y,xy\}$, $G_2=\{1,x\}$, and $G_3=\{1\}$, note that $G_2$ is abelian; that $G_2$ is normal in $G_1$ because $G_1$ is abelian, and the quotient is cyclic of order $2$. $G_1$ is normal in $G_0$ by construction, and the quotient is cyclic of order $3$. However, $G_2$ is **not** normal in $G$, since conjugating $x$ by $z$ gives $y$, which is not in $G_2$.

So you cannot hope to prove the result as you are attempting to.

The standard proof uses the commutator subgroup, and the derived series. Recall that if $G$ is a group, its commutator subgroup $G'$ (also denoted $[G,G]$) is defined to be
$$G' =[G,G] = \langle [x,y]\mid x,y\in G\rangle,$$
where $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. It is a good exercise to check that:

1. $G'$ is normal in $G$; in fact it is *characteristic*: for every automorphism $\phi$ of $G$, $\phi(G')=G'$. (In fact, it is *fully invariant*: for every *endomorphism* $f\colon G\to G$, we have $f(G')\subseteq G'$; and more, it is *functorial*, so that for *every homomorphism $f\colon G\to K$, $f(G')\subseteq K'$).
2. $G/G'$ is abelian.
3. If $N$ is any normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is abelian, then $G'\leq N$.

Define the *derived series of $G$* by:
$$\begin{align*}
G' =G^{(1)} & = [G,G];\\
G'' = (G')' = G^{(2)} &= [G',G'];\\
G^{(n+1)} = (G^{(n)})' &= [G^{(n)},G^{(n)}].
\end{align*}$$
Note that $G^{(k)}\triangleleft G$ for all $k$, thanks to point 1 above; because if $H$ is normal in $G$ and $K$ is *characteristic* in $H$, then $K$ is normal in $G$.

Now one proves the desired result, that if $G$ is solvable then it has an abelian tower in which every group that occurs in the tower is normal in $G$ as follows: Suppose that
$$1 = G_m \leq G_{m-1} \leq \cdots \leq G_1 \leq G$$
is a normal tower in which $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is abelian. Then $G'\leq G_1$; therefore, $G'' = (G')'\leq (G_1)'$. But since $G_1/G_2$ is abelian, $(G_1)'\leq G_2$, so $G''\leq G_2$.

Assume we have proven that $G^{(k)}\leq G_k$. Then $G^{(k+1)}\leq G_k'$. And since $G_k/G_{k+1}$ is abelian, then $G_k'\leq G_{k+1}$, so $G^{(k+1)}\leq G_{k+1}$.

Inductively, we conclude that $G^{(m)}\leq G_m=\{1\}$, so $G^{(m)}$ is trivial. Therefore, we have an abelian tower with
$$1 = G^{(m)}\leq G^{(m-1)}\leq \cdots \leq G' \leq G,$$
and all terms are normal in $G$, as desired. $\Box$

Comment: @Hermi That's point 2. $G^{(k+1)}$ is the commutator subgroup of $G^{(k)}$, so the quotient is abelian.

Comment: Yes! That makes sense. Thank you!.